# start mongod by service mongod start, attempt to create a lock file on a read-only directory /mgodb

Tags: mongodb

I changed `/etc/mongod.conf`'s dbpath to `/mgodb` and then I execute the follow command:

1. `mkdir /mgodb`
2. `chown mongod:mongod /mgodb`
3. `chmod 0755 /mgodb`

Then I run `service mongod start`, and get errors like:

> initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /mgodb

I tried to change `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`'s User and Group to root, it also get the same error.

But I cat run `mongod --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf` through command line.

Comment: Step 2. should probably be `chown -R mongod:mongod /mgodb`. `-R` being a recursive change to the folder and all sub-folders.

Answer (score 2):

If you look that /etc/mongod.conf, what are values of `processManagement.pidFilePath` and `storage.dbPath`? It sounds like that system tries to create files to some subdirectory, what don't exists or is not owned by user what is used to start mongod process.

You should never start your mongod with root user. And if you have done that, f.ex. when starting mongod to maintenance mode, always remember to `chown -R user: <dir>` data files back to the right owner.

Comment: thanks, 
chcon -Rv --type=mongod_var_lib_t /mgodbb
command resolved my problem. but i'm not fimilar with this command.
i'll find more document about this.